# Been struggling since few days ,How this 'continue' statement leaves 'a' and prints the rest of letter

Tags: python-3.x

```
my_string='Sammy'
for letter in my_string:
    if letter =='a':
        continue
    print(letter)
```

Ok i understood continue statement goes back top of closest enclosing loop, but how leaves 'm'
and prints the rest of letters... . I know i definitely missing some part could not catch it for days ?

Comment: Are you asking why the loop continues to print "m", "m", and "y" after encountering the "a"?

Comment: Nope, sorry for my terrible english. My question is what exactly does continue  and how ? In this code ?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, unfortunately. `continue`, like you said, goes back to the top of the closest enclosing loop, and moves on to the next item. So in our case, `for letter in my_string` takes each letter in the string `my_string`. If that letter is "a", it goes back and moves on to the next item (in this case "m"), *without executing the rest of the `for` loop*. If it's not "a", it moves on and prints the character.

Comment: Eyvallah abi şimdi biraz  anlamaya başladım.Dediğin gibi her bir harfı kontrol ediyor 'a' harfına gelince tekrardan yukarıya doğru çıkıyor(çünkü durum    if letter =='a' olduğu için) ve geri kalan harfleri mi kontrol ediyor diyorsun ?

Comment: (Affedersiniz, Türkçem pek iyi değil) - evet, aynen öyle.  `continue`, `for` loop içindeki kalan kod'u boşverip, sonraki nesneye geçiyor. Bu örnekte, harf 'a' ya eşit bulununca, gelecek harf'a geçiyor.

(Bunu galiba anlıyorsunuz, ama tekrarlıyım: `for` loopların içindeki kod, bir "iterable" objenin her nesnesi için tek tek değerlendiriliyor. `str` objeler, "harf listesi" olarak düşünebilir, ve o nedenle harf harf yineleniyor)

Comment: Onemli degil. Understood thanks a lot appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand how "continue" works, you have to understand how "break" works first.

In a loop, if your code sees break, the most close loop closes. What does it mean? Let's take a look at your code but change the "continue" with "break"

```
my_string='Sammy'
for letter in my_string:
    if letter =='a':
        break
    print(letter)
```

What do you think will happen? In normal circumstances, that for loop will print all the characters in your string While doing that, at letter a your code encounter a "break". Break will close your loop instantly. That means, your code will only be printing "S" letter since you're checking the letter first, and then printing it. Lets follow the code,

1) Create a variable named my_string and assign "Sammy" to it

2) Start a loop in letters of my_string variable

2-1) Is the letter "a"? No It's a "S"

2-2) Print the S

2-3) Go next letter

2-4) Is the letter "a"? Yes it is.

2-4-1) break

2-4-2) break the most close loop

2-4

2

3) Is there any more thing to do? No,

4) Close the program

Now lets talk about the "continue". Continue does similar thing too but instead of closing the loop complately, it just goes next state. Lets run your code this time.

```
my_string='Sammy'
for letter in my_string:
    if letter =='a':
        continue
    print(letter)
```

1) Create a variable named my_string and assign "Sammy" to it

2) Start a loop in letters of my_string variable

2-1) Is the letter "a"? No It's "S"

2-2) Print the "S"

2-3) Go next letter

2-4) Is the letter "a"? Yes it is.

2-4-1) continue

2-4-2) go next state (ignore the rest of the loop)

2-5) Is the letter "a"? No It's "m"

2-6) Print the "m"

2-7 Is the letter "a"? No It's "m" again

2-8) Print the "m"

2-9) Is the letter "a"? No It's "y"

2-10) Print the "y"

2-11) Is there any more letters? No there isn't. Close the loop

2-

3) Is there anymore thing to do? No there isn't

4) Close the program

Continue send you to the next state, not the beggining of the current state or something.

If you write something like this,

```
a = 5
while a<10:
    continue
    a=a+1
```

You will enter a infinite loop because everytime you see the continue, your code will go the next state. But it's a while loop and while loops doesn't do anything about its variables. In next state, the a will be 5 again and again.

Comment: Eyvallah kardesh .

Comment: Nice effort.  It is important to note that it is the string that gets assigned to the variable and not the other way around.

Comment: Ups, I fixed it